# Jacoco Maven coverage report always 0%

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube, code-coverage

I've this problem with Jacoco maven plugin in IntelliJ IDEA 2020.
I put the Jacoco plugin configuration in my pom.xml maven file and then executed the `mvn clean install` command. It generates the target\site folder but when I open the index.html file it shows me a coverage of 0%, listing all my classes, although I get a 92% coverage in IntelliJ's integrated tool. The jacoco.exec file is generated in target folder, but it's empty!
How can I fix this issue?

Here's my pom.xml fragment:

```
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <source>14</source>
          <target>14</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.5</version>
        <configuration>
          <excludes>
            <exclude>META-INF/**</exclude>
          </excludes>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>pre-unit-test</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>post-unit-test</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>report</goal>
              <goal>check</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <rules>
              </rules>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

I'm using the latest Java version (14).
Thanks in advance!

Comment: how do you start the jacoco test with maven?

Comment: mvn test, is it ok?

Comment: you tried already any of the goals listed on the jacoco maven plugin page?

Comment: I tried prepare agent, check and report ones.

Comment: tried the snapshot version of jacoco but still getting 0% of coverage... any ideas?